# Hive Error - FAILED: ParseException line 5:0 missing EOF at 'HAVING' near 'ASC'

Tags: sql, hive

I am learning hive and I am getting below error not sure why?

```
ERROR: missing EOF at 'HAVING' near 'ASC'
```

I am using below query on my table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), maker ,ROUND(AVG(price_eur),2) AS average_price
FROM valid_cars_data
GROUP BY maker
ORDER BY average_price ASC
HAVING average_price < 20000
LIMIT 5;
```

Am I missing something here. Any pointers will help. Thanks!

Comment: I also tried running the query without HAVING and it works fine. SELECT COUNT(*), maker ,ROUND(AVG(price_eur),2) AS average_price
FROM valid_cars_data
GROUP BY maker
ORDER BY average_price ASC;

Comment: I think you need the HAVING after the GROUP BY and before the ORDER BY